# Login failed for user 'administrator' when connecting PHP to SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a Windows 10 PC that has the Apache web server installed. I want to connect my PHP web program to SQL Server, but an error message appears as below:

```
Connection could not be established. Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 28000 [SQLSTATE] => 28000 [1] => 18456 [code] => 18456 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'administrator'. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'administrator'. ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 28000 [SQLSTATE] => 28000 [1] => 18456 [code] => 18456 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'administrator'. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'administrator'. ) )
```

This is my connection file:

```
<?php  
/*  
Connect to the local server using Windows Authentication and specify  
the AdventureWorks database as the database in use. To connect using  
SQL Server Authentication, set values for the "UID" and "PWD"  
 attributes in the $connectionInfo parameter. For example:  
$connectionInfo = array("UID" => $uid, "PWD" => $pwd, "Database"=>"AdventureWorks");  
*/  
$serverName = "192.168.0.6";
$connectionInfo = array("UID"=>"administrator", "PWD"=>"tes", "Database"=>"gm");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);

if($conn)
{
     echo "Connection established.\n";
}
else
{
     echo "Connection could not be established.\n";
     die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}  
  
//-----------------------------------------------  
// Perform operations with connection.  
//-----------------------------------------------  
  
/* Close the connection. */  
sqlsrv_close($conn);  
?>
```

For login to SQL Server Management Studio, I use Windows Server Login.
I've enabled server authentication to "SQL Server and Windows Authentication Mode", so I also enabled "TCP/IP" and "Named Pipes", but it still doesn't work, and I still get the error above.

Comment: You don't specify `UID` and `PWD` when connecting to SQL Server with Windows logons. Instead of `UID` and `PWD` you specify `Trusted_Connection=True` (or `Yes`) and the client process shares its identity token to authenticate with SQL Server.

Comment: What does the SQL Server's logs say? Authentication errors passed to the application layer are intentionally vague.

Comment: Do you wat to use Windows Aithentication or SQL Authentication? If the former, you should use `Trusted_Connection=True`. If the latter, do you actually have a SQL login called `administrator`?

Comment: Can you give me a more detailed answer and tell me what I have to do to resolve this issue? Because I don't know what I have to do with this script Trusted_Connection=True and where I have to put it. @Charlieface

Comment: Well you need to answer my questions: Windows Auth or SQL Auth? If the latter, are you sure you hav a login set up correctly? If the former: looks like from the documentation that  you just need to remove the `UID` and `PWD` parameters https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php#example-2018 but obviously you need to be logged in to the correct Windows user when running the PHP code.

Comment: I use Windows Auth. I removed the UID and PWD and get this error: `Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'` @Charlieface

Comment: OK then PHP is not running under a user that the SQL Server machine recognizes. It should be running using a AD domain account, and both machines joined to the domain. Although there is a hack to make it work with local users only (same name and matching password on both machines).